# ng not found (Docker Compose)

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to build and run, but it says that "ng not found" and finally, that the container exited with code 127. Well, running `npm install` and then `ng serve --open` is sufficient for run my application outside a docker container, but inside it, simple doesn't works. I tried do `RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod`, but `.bin` folder isn't there (what I think that is the problem, but I really don't know how to solve it, because even `.dockerignore` is not ignoring `.bin`). So, what should I do?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent
COPY . .
RUN ls node_modules
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I also tried to `npm install @angular/cli -g', but I get into another error...

Comment: Did you try npx ng serve?

Comment: I tried now, and at least not using Docker, it works just like ng serve --open (without docker too)

Comment: Are you getting the error building the image, or running the container?  If running the container, are you hiding the image content with some sort of mount over `/usr/src/app`?

Comment: I'm getting the error when I try `docker-compose up --build` and when I try to `docker run -it --rm (...)`

Comment: Also, when removing `--production` on `npm install`, it stops on `RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app` and then tell me that it is having connection issues `ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT`

Comment: Finally, removing `RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app`, the program runs, but I have no access for a whole bunch of files and directories, and the angular app cannot compile. Something like `Error: EACCESS: permission denied mkdir '/usr/src/app/.angular`